# What exactly is meant by "an integer basis of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $H^*(M)$"?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I thought I understood the concept of a cohomology ring, but am confused by the following statement found in a textbook. Context: M is a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$.

"Let us choose an integer basis $e_0,e_1,...,e_n$ of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $H^*(M)$ such that $e_0=1 \in H^0(M)$ and each basis element $e_v$ has pure degree".

They then go on to define the intersection matrix

$ g_{uv} = \int e_u   \smile e_v $

From the identification of the cup product with the wedge product on forms I would have assumed an integer basis for $H^*(M) = \bigoplus_k H^k(M)$ is $e_0,...,e_{N}$ where $N= \sum_k \mbox{dim} H^k(M)$. What fundamental concept am I misunderstanding to explain why a basis for $H^*(M)$ is $e_0,e_1,...,e_n$?

Comment: The author probably just forgot that he or she had already used $n$ for $\frac{1}{2}\dim M$. The $e_0, \dots, e_N$ you describe make more sense.

Comment: I've seen it elsewhere also. I am not sure my understanding of an "integer basis" is correct. Could you please summarize quickly?

Comment: "Basis" is not really the right word if $H^*(M)$ is not a free abelian group, but in general it should just mean a minimal generating set.

Comment: And generally this should be the one I describe meaning $e_0,...,e_n$ implies special circumstances?

Comment: @Tom: The torsion in $H^*M$ contributes nothing to $g$ (cf. the intersection form), so presumably the author is just talking about a basis of the free part of $H^*M$; that is, elements $e_0, \dots, e_N$ for which the map $\mathbb{Z}^N \to H^*M$ given by $a \to a_i e_i$ (implicit summation) is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "integer basis" means unless $H^{\bullet}(M)$ is free. If it's free, then it means the obvious thing. I agree with the comments that the appearance of $n$ here is a typo and should be ignored; it should be $N - 1$ (since you've started at $e_0$).